# Workflow to Export All Tasks on Project Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, project-server

I want to write a workflow that will export a list of all the tasks for all projects on a project server instance to an excel file. Is this possible in SP2013 or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.